# trouble capturing output of a subshell that has been backgrounded

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, background-process

Attempting to make a "simple" parallel function in bash.  The problem is currently that when the line to capture the output is backgrounded, the output is lost.  If that line is not backgrounded, the output is captured fine, but this of course defeats the purpose of the function.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  cluster="${1:-web100s}"
  hosts=($(inventory.pl bash "$cluster" | sort -V))
  cmds="${2:-uptime}"

  parallel=10
  cx=0
  total=0
  for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    output[$total]=$(echo -en "$host: ")
    echo "${output[$total]}"
    output[$total]+=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 "$host" "$cmds") &
    cx=$((cx + 1))
    total=$((total + 1))
    if [[ $cx -gt $parallel ]]; then
      wait >&/dev/null
      cx=0
    fi
  done

  echo -en "***** DONE *****\n     Results\n"

  for ((i=0; i<= $total; i++)); do
    echo "${output[$i]}"
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your command (the assignment) is run in a subshell, so this assignment can't influence the parent shell. This boils down to this:

```
a=something
a='hello senorsmile' &
echo "$a"
```

Can you guess what the output is? the output is, of course,

```
something
```

and not `hello senorsmile`. The only way for the subshell to communicate with the parent shell is to use an IPC (interprocess communication), in one form or another. I don't have any solution to propose, I only tried to explain why it fails.

If you think of it, it should make sense. What do you think of this?

```
a=$( echo a; sleep 1000000000; echo b ) &
```

The command immediately returns (after forking)... but the output is only going to be fully available in... over 31 years.

Comment: This makes sense and goes along with what I suspected was happening, despite not quite being able to articulate it.  The only solution I have for now is writing out to tmp files... but an ideal solution will be not having to write to disk.

Comment: @senorsmile: writing to temp files is actually fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a shell variable in the background this way is effectively meaningless. Bash does have built in co-processing which should work for you:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Coprocesses

Comment: this could solve the problem, although for now I've just decided to write out to files in /tmp and clean them up after.  coproc definitely seems a bit touchy.